# I am looking for CHM alternatives

Tags: chm

I've heard that CHM is out-of-date and I can't find any newer alternatives. Can you suggest any? I'm writing an app in Java

Comment: CHM is still the newest generally available help technology for Windows.There simply is no sane substitute yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the proprietary CHM file format is normally generated by Micosoft HH Workshop (hhw.exe). It’s 20 years old und was first shipped with IE4 and Windows 95. It’s deep integrated to the Windows operating system.

HTML Help is in maintenance mode, which means no new features are expected for either the runtime or the compiler. All mainstream development on HH has stopped – but HTMLHelp (.chm help files) is still recommended as software application help (for offline (local) help).

You should use JavaHelp for creating .CHM-like help pages for Java applications.